# How to merge 2 Django QuerySets in one and make a SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, distinct, geodjango

###### models.py

```
class SinglePoint(models.Model):
    attributes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    geom = models.PointField() #Kartenposition
    objects = models.GeoManager()

class Connection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #points = models.ManyToManyField(SinglePoint) #OLD
    p1 = models.ForeignKey(SinglePoint, related_name='p1_set') #NEW
    p2 = models.ForeignKey(SinglePoint, related_name='p2_set') #NEW
    obs = models.ManyToManyField(Observation, blank=True)
    conds = models.ManyToManyField(Condition, blank=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
  
class Meta:
    order_with_respect_to = 'p1'
```

In my view.py:

```
...
p1_points = SinglePoint.objects.filter(name=name)
p2_points = SinglePoint.objects.filter(name=name)
...
```

Before I switched to ForeignKey, it worked with:

```
points = SinglePoint.objects.filter(name=name)
```

How to 'join' these two QuerySets to one QuerySet and make a distinct()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 74):

It took me a while to find this

```
all_points = p1_points | p2_points
```

Comment: What is the name of this '|' operator in python ?

Comment: In python, the `|` operator is called a "bitwise or" or a "union set" operator, depending on the context of how it is used:

Comment: it can also be called "or" operator :)

Answer (score 9):

I am not familiar with geodjango, but combining QuerySets into one QuerySet is possible via the Q-Object and Boolean Operators. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Example:

```
Q(p1_points) | Q(p2_points)
```

I can't help you further, because I am not really sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to get all SinglePoint instances in my Project without double SinglePoint instances (distinct). It was no problem with a ManyToMany-Field, because then I accessed them with .filter(connection__vektordata__ ...).distinct() and now I have two Filds: .filter(p1_set__vektordata__ ... and .filter(p2_set__vektordata__ ...)

Comment: Sorry, I meant "Fields" not "Filds"

Comment: results = Q(p1_points) | Q(p2_points)
results.children gives me [[<SinglePoint: A>, <SinglePoint: X1>], [<SinglePoint: X1>, <SinglePoint: X2>]] but I wish to have [<SinglePoint: A>, <SinglePoint: X1>, <SinglePoint: X1>, <SinglePoint: X2>] to call distinct()

Answer (score 7):

I think [Q queries](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) can achieve what you need like this:

```
points = SinglePoint.objects.filter(
    Q(name=name) |
    Q(name=name)
).distinct()
```

Answer (score 3):

`p1_points.union(p2_points)`

See [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.union)

Comment: The problem with `union()` is that it restricts the actions to the resulting queryset. For instance, you can't `.filter()` or `.annotate()` which is a pretty big drawback. Read more about it [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#union).

Answer (score 1):

You can use ["|"(bitwise or)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators#The_Operators:) to combine the querysets of the same model and [distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) and [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) as shown below:

```py
all_points = (p1_points | p2_points).distinct().values_list('name')
```

And, you can use `|=` to add the queryset of the same model as shown below:

```py
all_points = p1_points 
all_points |= p2_points
all_points = all_points.distinct().values_list('name')
```