# Django ORM conditional filter LIKE CASE WHEN THEN

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm using Django 1.11, Postgresql 9.2, python 3.4

I want to select data based on table's column named `event_type` if event type is **single** then compare date that should be of same date (today's) date else select all dates of given (today's) date that type would be of **recurring**.

But can't we manage this using single query? Like we do `CASE` and `WHEN`, `THEN` in Aggregation? I tried using `Q` object but no luck. 
I want to check when value is 'single' then add condition, else another condition.

I could not find any good solution, currently I've achieved using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125844/howto-merge-2-django-querysets-in-one-and-make-a-select-distinct)

```
today = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
single_events = crm_models.EventsMeta.objects.filter(
    event_type == "single",
    repeat_start=today
)

recurring_events = crm_models.EventsMeta.objects.filter(
    event_type == "recurring"
    repeat_start__lte=today
)

all_events = single_events | recurring_events
```

For more information my model is:

```
class EventsMeta(models.Model):
    event_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=(("single","Single"),("recurring","Recurring")), 
                            null=False, blank=False,default='single',verbose_name="Event Type")
    repeat_start = models.DateTimeField()
    repeat_end = models.DateTimeField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine many Q objects with `()` signs. I your case I suppose this will work:

```
single_events = crm_models.EventsMeta.objects.filter(
    (Q(event_type="single") & Q(repeat_start=today)) |
    (Q(event_type="recurring") & Q(repeat_start__lte=today))
)
```

Comment: My bad, this was very simple. `()` Did the trick, actually I missed in my `Q` condition, thanks. This has got worked.

Answer (score -1):

use this:-

```
today = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
single_events = crm_models.EventsMeta.objects.filter(
    event_type__in = ["single", "recurring"]
    repeat_start=today
)
```

Comment: there's `repeat_start__lte=today` in the recurring case.