# Django query conditional field selector

Tags: django, conditional-statements

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, related_name="children")    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

Need to apply search from **Child** by some *term* stating:

If **Child**'s *name* is not empty or not NULL then we compare *term* with **Child**'s *name* else - compare *term* with **Parent**'s *name*.

Something like:

```
search_result = Child.objects.filter(
    if 
        Q(name__isnull=True) | Q(name='') 
    then 
        parent__name__icontains=term
    else 
        name__icontains=term
)
```

so that having:

```
parent = Parent(name="Smith").save()
ch1 = Child(parent=parent, name="Smithson").save()
ch2 = Child(parent=parent, name="Watson").save()
ch3 = Child(parent=parent).save()
```

The search by term "smith" would result:

```
[ch1, ch3]
```

Comment: Dude write some explanation , add some of your work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple of Q objects with `()` signs.

```
from django.db.models import Q 
search_result = Child.objects.filter(
    ((Q(name__isnull=True) | Q(name='')) & Q(parent__name__icontains=term)) |
    (Q(name__isnull=False) & Q(name__icontains=term))
)
```

Which means either match `((Q(name__isnull=True) | Q(name='')) & Q(parent__name__icontains=term))` 
this condition or match `(Q(name__isnull=False) & Q(name__icontains=term))`

Ref : [Django ORM conditional filter LIKE CASE WHEN THEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48982618/django-orm-conditional-filter-like-case-when-then)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but something like this:

```
name = "smith"
Child.objects.filter(Q(name__iexact=name) or Q(name=None) & Q(parent__name__iexact=name))
```